# How can I make my fetch 'GET' request to a REST API on node.js not reload the page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, fetch, reload

I am new to web development and am having an issue with fetching to a REST API. I want the fetch request to be ran as soon as the page is traversed to. I am first taking a cookie value and adding it to the end of the url route so that my backend can retrieve it from the session store and return the JSON object with the user data back to the front end. The get request goes to that url and it successfully sends a response however the page is reloaded after it gets the response. I will include the code from my front end JS file, Index.js on the back end, the routes JS file, and the controllers JS file where I send the response.

my profile.js

```
let getSessionId = function (callback) {
  const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
  const cookie = cookies.find(c => c.trim().startsWith('UserCookie'));
  const userCookieId = cookie ? cookie.split('=')[1] : null;
  console.log(userCookieId);

  const sessionId = {
    id: userCookieId
  }

  const userURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/' + sessionId.id;

  callback(userURL);
}

let getUserData = function (url,callback) {
  console.log(url);
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
  })
  .then(response => {
    if(response.ok)
    {
      console.log("Got a response");
      callback();
    }
    else
    {
      console.log('Error: ' + response.status);
      callback();
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

let start = function () {
  const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
  const cookie = cookies.find(c => c.trim().startsWith('hasLoaded='));
  const hasLoaded = cookie ? parseInt(cookie.split('=')[1]) : 0;
  console.log(hasLoaded);
  if(hasLoaded === 0)
  {
    loadData();
  }
}

let loadData = function () {
  getSessionId((userURL) => {
    console.log("URL: " + userURL);
    getUserData(userURL,() => {
      console.log("Test2");
      return false;
    })
  })
};

start();
```

my index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const sqlite = require("better-sqlite3");
const SqliteStore = require("better-sqlite3-session-store")(session)
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

//Routes
const usersRoutes = require('./Users/global_users.js');
const leagues = require('./Leagues/global_leagues.js');
const teams = require('./Teams/teams.js');
const players = require('./Players/global_players.js');

const app = express();
const PORT = 5000;

//set up session store
const db = new sqlite("DreamTeam/Back-End/sessions.db", { verbose: console.log });
let sessionStore = new SqliteStore({
    client: db, 
    expired: {
      clear: true,
      intervalMs: 900000 //ms = 15min
    }
});

//sets up user sessions
sessID = uuidv4();
app.use(session({
    secret: 'my secret key',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: false,
        sameSite: 'none'
    }
}));

//allows connections 
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:5500', //configured to accept connection from html pages launched with live server
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
    allowedMethods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    credentials: true
}));

//used for REST API data transfer
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//adds a route to the url
app.use('/users', usersRoutes);
app.use('/leagues', leagues);
app.use('/teams', teams);
app.use('/players', players);

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Running on port: http://localhost:${PORT}`));

module.exports = { sessionStore };
```

my global_users.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { get_user, login, show_all, create_user, delete_user, update_firstname, update_lastname, update_username, update_password, update_email, update_bio, update_position, update_profile_picture } = require('../controllers/global_users.js');

const router = express.Router();

router.use(bodyParser.json());

//list all Users to the console
router.get('/', show_all);

//Create a User
router.post('/', create_user);

//login user (User Authentication)
router.post('/login', login);

//Get a User's Info
router.get('/:sessId', get_user);

//Delete a User
router.delete('/:id', delete_user);

//Update User Info
router.patch('/update_username/:id', update_username);
router.patch('/update_email/:id', update_email);
router.patch('/update_bio/:id', update_bio);
router.patch('/update_lastname/:id', update_lastname);
router.patch('/update_firstname/:id', update_firstname);
router.patch('/update_position/:id', update_position);
router.patch('/update_password/:id', update_password);
router.patch('/update_picture/:id', update_profile_picture);

module.exports = router;
```

Lastly, the controllers file (cut to just include the function definition of router.get('/:sessId', get_user);

```
const get_path = (callback) => {
    const pwd = process.cwd();
    let db_path = pwd;
    db_path = db_path + "\\DreamTeam\\Back-End\\database.db";
    db_path = db_path.replace(/\\/g,"/");

    callback(db_path);
}

const get_path_session = (callback) => {
    const pwd = process.cwd();
    let db_path = pwd;
    db_path = db_path + "\\DreamTeam\\Back-End\\sessions.db";
    db_path = db_path.replace(/\\/g,"/");

    callback(db_path);
}

const get_user = (req, res) => {
    const { sessId } = req.params;

    get_path_session( (path) => {
        sess.open(path);
        sess.get_session(sessId, (sessData) => {
            console.log("Got " + sessData.user.id);
            const id = sessData.user.id;
            sess.close();
            get_path( (path) => {
                db.open(path);
                db.get_all(id, (username,first_name,last_name,playerID, teamID, email,bio,pos) => {
                    console.log(username + " " + first_name + " " + last_name + " " + playerID + " " + teamID + " " + email + " " + bio + " " + pos)
                    const userData = {
                        firstName: first_name
                    };
                    res.send(userData);
                    db.close();
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Right now I am only sending a JSON object with a first name to test. I have tried using window.onload() but It still reloads everytime.

Note that I had at one point a cookie called hasLoaded that was supposed to be used as a sort of "global boolean" so I could set it to 1 after the response was recieved. This does stop the infinite loop of reloading the page however it is still reloaded once which I do not want to have happen.

I have messed around with CORS policy stuff as well as I am not sure if that is causing the issue but I am not experienced enough to know what I am really doing there.

Also, I have other fetch requests in this project that do not cause the page to be reloaded so I copied those ones line for line into my profile.js and went to the page and it still caused the page to reload constantly. Maybe it's got something to do with the HTML? I can attach that too if needed but I should mention that I did try this with a blank HTML page and had the same issue.

Also probably your first thought is "Why is he not using a framework?". That is a really good question and it's because when I started this project I didn't know frameworks existed.
I know this will probably get torn to shreds as I am a novice and am probably doing things in an alien way but I am open to learning which is why I am asking the question. I have been banging my head against a wall for a while now with this so any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I found therein the issue lies. I know this has no answers but incase someone comes along with the same issue I will update this as I learn more.

The issue has something to do with the session store I am using. The "better-sqlite3-session-store" is causing the page to reload everytime I make a fetch request. I think what I may end up doing is just having my own sqlite3 database and call it the session store and manually code in the addition of sessions to the store, this way I can avoid having to use this module that is giving unexpected behaviors. Will update if I am able to find a fix to make the store not do this.

EDIT 2:

I have since created my own home-baked session store that creates and deletes sessions when a user logs in and logs out and messing with this database is not causing my front-end pages to reload. I probably don't need to keep this question up anymore but I'll leave it because I read a lot of similar issues with fetch requests so maybe someone could find this useful.

Or people can just have fun roasting my code, whichever is cool with me.

Comment: Why all the synchronous callback based functions? Just `return` from them!

Comment: I will be honest I had not even really thought about just returning. Learning synchronous code for the last 3 years made me super confused when I was introduced to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript so I pounded it into my brain how to use callback functions not really thinking when they are actually appropriate. I guess I got carried away and am living in callback hell now lol. Thank you for the tip! I am sure it will make my future code more readable.

Comment: No worries! Also `async/await` keywords will help you getting rid of callbacks.